# Selenium Rspec Tests are not running on Amazon ec2 ubuntu OS

Tags: ruby, selenium, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rspec

I have already deployed my Ruby app on the cloud, but when I run my tests on ec2 instance I get this error:

`:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/service.rb:112:in 'connect_until_stable': unable to connect to Mozilla geckodriver 127.0.0.1:4444 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)`

NB:- The same rspec tests are running fine on the localhost.

Error image:

I have also added the port no-4444 in this security group. I have already put geckodriver to the path where my Ruby has been installed.

Comment: We tend to discourage images containing just text, as they are hard to read. Would you be so kind as to select the error text from your console and paste it into your question instead of the image? You can use the "code" button to add a block preformatting effect.

Comment: if you are using firefox versions > 48, you need Geckodriver on your path.

Answer (score 0):

Download right geckodriver as per your operating system from below url:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Then unzip it and run below commands for Ubuntu/Linux OS:

```
chmod +x geckodriver
sudo mv -f geckodriver /usr/local/share/geckodriver
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/geckodriver /usr/local/bin/geckodriver
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/geckodriver /usr/bin/geckodriver
```

Comment: I have tried this, It doesn't work. Do you any alternate solution which works cent % correctly. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to Firefox 47.0.1 resolves this issue for me.

It is enought to download a standalone version and point your webdriver to it.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path = 'PATH_to_standalone_version'
```